# Keeping VirtualBox working across Linux kernel upgrade

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine

I recently installed [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) on my Linux host.  I noticed while running the install script that some kernel modules were compiled/installed.

I upgrade the kernel (building from source) quite often.  What do I need to do with regards to VirtualBox when I upgrade the kernel?  Would I have to completely re-install, or is there a way to just recompile the modules against the updated kernel?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a Stack Overflow topic. best on the unix SE, but there is no migration as yet, so could be either Super User of Server Fault depending on your use case. This question will likely be migrated to one of those sites soon...

Comment: @dmckee - As a stackoverflow.com "newbie" I was unaware that that question seemed inappropriate for that site.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu for instance I just run

/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

when I install a new kernel.

Comment: Thanks - my distro is Slackware, but I just noted that the init script /etc/rc.d/rc.vboxdrv will compile kernel modules if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Recompiling the kernel modules is sufficient, unless the module API changes (which does happen) at which point you would need a new version of at least the kernel modules.